# ubuntu/trusty64 から立ち上げた VM の容量を拡張するには？

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

Vagrant + VirtualBox で、 ubuntu (`ubuntu/trusty64`) をインストールしました。

この box を `vagrant up` した際に作成される VM のルートボリュームのサイズは 40G です。これはいろいろと物足りないので、拡張したいと考えました。

これを実現する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の手順でできます。

※はじめにバックアップ (`vagrant package`) をとっておくことを推奨します。

#### VM の場所などを特定する

以下で特定できます。

```
# vm の一覧を表示
VBoxManage list vms

# 上で表示された vm のうち、詳細を見たい vm を指定。
# SATAControler: みたいなものが、下記で使う仮想ディスクへのパス
VBoxManage showvminfo ubuntu64_default_1491551785012_65723
```

#### vmdk を vdi に変換し、サイズを変更する。

vmdk はボリュームのリサイズが (少なくとも VirtualBox からでは)できないので、まず vdi 形式に変換します。

```
# 上で特定した VM のディレクトリに移動する。
cd ${vm_dir}  # e.g. ~/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu64_default_1491551785012_65723/

# ディスク情報を確認
VBoxManage showhdinfo ./box-disk1.vmdk
# ディスクフォーマットを変換しながら clone
VBoxManage clonehd ./box-disk1.vmdk clone-disk1.vdi --format vdi
# ディスクをリサイズ (81920MB == 80G)
VBoxManage modifyhd ./clone-disk1.vdi --resize 81920
```

#### ディスクをアタッチする

ここの作業は、VM のストレージ設定がどのような構成になっているかに依存します。
ポイントは、もともとのボリュームファイルを新しいボリュームファイル置き換えるように、設定すること。

基本的に GUI から操作してこの設定は達成できる様子です。

```
# 今回作業していた VM では、 SATA　コントローラーからルートボリュームだけがアタッチされている構成であった。
# この場合は以下のコマンドで実行可能。
# vm_name: e.g. ubuntu64_default_1491551785012_65723
VBoxManage storageattach ${vm_name} --storagectl "SATAController" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium clone-disk1.vdi

# 確認
VBoxManage showhdinfo ./clone-disk1.vdi
```

#### VM を再起動する

```
cd ${vagrantfile_folder}
vagrant up
```